# What is the meaning of 'semantic errors' or 'semantically erroneous' in 422 errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, httprequest, http-status-code-422

I'm looking through an advanced, security related Ruby on Rails tutorial and it's talking about 422 HTTP responses as "the client submitted request was well formed but semantically invalid". I have also seen the latter part rendered as 'semantic errors' or 'semantically erroneous'.

In the example given this was due to Rails checking for an authenticity token, but I significantly feel there is a lot more to the HTTP response.

I would be particularly grateful for a canonical definition from an established community member as to what 'semantically invalid/errors/erroneous' means. What is the general rule that makes a request well formed but not semantically valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `422` (unprocessable entity) status code is given to indicate that the server *understood the request*, but *could not process the logic*.

It can be used to indicate things like **logic problems** (e.g. you asked for an invalid date range to filter on), and **validation issues** (e.g. you didn't specify a title - which is required). "Semantic error" in this case simply means "logic error".

This distinguishes it from things like lack of permissions (`401` or `403` is more appropriate), and also from a generic `400` status which can indicate that the server couldn't understand the request (i.e. it was a malformed request).

Comment: If it's well formed is that not logical? Am I being too English language?

Comment: To build onto this with an analogy to language, just as a question can be syntactically valid but semantically invalid ("is the book unemployed?"), so can a web request.

Comment: Well formed = conforms to your API specification. That is quite different from valid logic

Comment: I understand and am amused by the literary example, but I don't understand how it applies to the tech

Comment: @gwcodes so it applies everything the API asks for but... [?]

Comment: @RailsKiddie: let's look at a really simple example. I have a GET endpoint that let's you query articles between a `to` and `from` date range. It expects two integer (timestamp) parameters. If you were to send a request without either parameter, I would return `400` - you didn't follow my instructions, so your _syntax_ is wrong. If you sent a request where `from` was _less than_ `to`, then we have a _semantic_ error. Technically everything is valid, but your query makes no logical sense.

Comment: Ah, so it basically means that to the API it would make sense, but to established standards it doesn't, right?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Here's another way of looking at it - the status code that you return can help users to troubleshoot any errors. If I get a `400`, I need to look at the structure of what I'm requesting. If I get a `401`, then I need to check my authorisation keys. If I get a `422`, I should check the _values_ that I'm sending, because the server is indicating that they don't make sense (from the perspective of the application logic)

Comment: Thank you @gwcodes 
These codes can be very tricky and tough to distinguish. This makes a lot of sense, usually, ppl throw a generic 400 and 404 for almost everything.

Answer (score 1):

I got this particular semantic error while posting resources into the database via postman.

After clean examination of the payload which I am sending, I found that the Json payload is not having the correct format that Database schema is expecting. For example, I am having one value as string instead of an array of strings in my payload. Later it got posted successfully with 201 response.